# VMware purchase for solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, vmware, hybrid, disaster-recovery

I really need this question answered for purchase, need to know if I  have to buy any new licenses for
 DR and have to spin up in the cloud.

I haves VMWare vmc onsite.  120VMS. Some are for VDI others run apps and databases.

will set up VMWare VMC in AWS for DR only, meaning all vms will be shutdown and not running unless there is a DR event.

1. What are the licensing costs to have the 2nd VMware environment built out at AWS but in pause/shutdown mode.
2. What configuration steps are required to turn the AWS environment on, both for VDI and the other servers.

They should be able to provide pricing and baseline process for this set up

Comment: This is off-topic and is probably getting closed. Maybe check out [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Is it off topic?

Comment: IMO yes and I flagged your question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, this is something that would be better discussed with your local VMware account/sales team.

From my knowledge, VMWonAWS is sold on a per-host basis. If a host has resources being consumed (CPU/RAM/Storage), there will be a charge for that host. There are no capabilities to pause or shutdown a host, either you're consuming resources on the host or it is removed from your SDDC's inventory.

Turning on an environment is the process of deploying an SDDC. After the configuration has been applied, you have a vCenter that's setup and ready for you to run your workloads.